# Is the code executed when I create instance of a function?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am new to JS and wanted to ask you about when I create instance of the below function then Is it executed like when I use `PageState()`? What exactly happens when I use `const page = new PageState()`;

```js
function PageState(){
        let currentState = new homeState();
    
        this.change = function(state){
            currentState=state;
        }
    }
    
const page = new PageState();
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You can read this [`new operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) for more info

Comment: note you are not creating an instance of the function PageState but an object whose constructor is the function PageState  - ie.. page() will not work. as page is not a function.

Comment: You might want to look at ES6 classes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes if you are doing oop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly happens when I use `const page = new PageState();`

A new object is created with the object that `PageState.prototype` refers to as its prototype, and then the code in `PageState` runs. The code in `PageState` creates a new `homeState` object and a new function object (for the `change` property). (That `change` function is *not* executed by the code shown, but could be executed via `page.change(/*...*/);` later.) Although a new function object is created every time, it will reuse the underlying code (not that there's a lot in this case :-) ) on any modern JavaScript engine. That new function is a *closure* over the context where it was created, which means it has access to the `currentState` local variable even after `PageState` returns.

More on closures:

- On my anemic little blog: [*Closures are Not Complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)
- Here on SO: [*How do JavaScript closures work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to have a working example. It's commented with some explanation throughout.

```js
function PageState(){
        this.currentState = 0;

        this.change = function(state){
          this.currentState = state;
        }
    }

// Create variable with function Page State in it
const page = new PageState();

// Access one properties of page, this example an integer which is set to 0
console.log("Initial value of current state: " + page.currentState)

// You can also store functions as properties
// You can call this function like this:
result = page.change(1)

// I saved the result in a variable to let you see the returned value (currentState)
console.log("Changed value of current state: " + page.currentState)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function with `new` keyword, you are creating a new object. You can add properties and methods to this object through `this`. You can create local variables in this function, they will not be available in the created object. I recommend you to see `Module pattern`.